# Does a card have a keyword if it has the same effect as said keyword?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was looking at [Contingency Plan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bContingency%20Plan%5d) and found the effect surprisingly similar to the keyword Surveil. To compare, first the wording of Contingency Plan and then the wording of the Surveil keyword:

> Look at the top five cards of your library. Put any number of them into your graveyard and the rest back on top of your library in any order.

And

> 701.41a To "surveil N" means to look at the top N cards of your library, then put any number of them into your graveyard and the rest on top of your library in any order.

They quite clearly are the same, so can I assume the card states "Surveil 5" instead? And if so, does it trigger abilities which state "Whenever you surveil ..."?

Comment: @Glorfindel Good find; but I've closed that other question as a duplicate of this one, because this one has a more generally useful subject, more details in the post, and more details in the answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> so can I assume the card states "Surveil 5" instead? And if so, does it trigger abilities which state "Whenever you surveil ..."?

Nope, the Oracle text is leading. In general, cards from earlier editions don't retroactively get 'keyworded'; the only exceptions so far have been [evergreen keywords](http://markrosewater.tumblr.com/post/180093974523/mark-why-hasnt-sultai-ascendancy-been-erratad) like lifelink, vigilance, and shroud; block-specific keywords like surveil only apply to cards from that block.

Comment: The lifelink retroactive keywording came back to bite them, too.  The M10 rules update changed the behavior of lifelink, and forced them to go back and de-errata the cards which no longer had lifelink.  But a few cards had been reprinted since then, and got to keep lifelink because of that, more or less getting accidental functional errata.